# Running `sox.exe` from Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I run this command from Windows cmd line successfully:

`c:\cygwin\bin\sox.exe -r 16000 -c 1 c:/work/out/in_fixed.s32 c:/work/out/out_float.f32`

However, I fail to run it from Python:

```
import subprocess

if __name__ == "__main__":

    sox = 'c:/cygwin/bin/sox.exe'
    in_fixed = 'c:/work/out/in_fixed.s32'
    out_float = 'c:/work/out/out_fixed.f32'

    cmnd = '-r 16000 -c 1 ' + in_fixed + ' ' + out_float

    subprocess.call([sox, cmnd])
```

Ther error is:

```
/usr/bin/sox FAIL sox: Rate value ` 16000 -c 1 c:/work/out/in_fixed.s32 c:/work/out/out_fixed.f32' is not a positive number.
```

How to launch this command from python properly?

Answer (score 1):

Try separating your arguments

```
subprocess.call([sox, '-r', str(16000), '-c', str(1), in_fixed, out_float])
```

If that doesn't work, you can force CMD usage with `shell=True`.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn´t work. I need to put 16000 and 1 into quotes, so this works: subprocess.call([sox, '-r', '16000', '-c', '1', in_fixed, out_float ]). Could zou please fix the answer. Still, this solution is not very convenient; I´d still like to pass my arguments in one variable.

Comment: Then pass as a variable and call `sox.split()`...obviously that won't work when there's spaces in your command, though.